# Is the honeycomb lattice the double graph of another graph?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, combinatorial-geometry

Associated to any planar graph $G$ there is another graph called its *double graph*, denoted by $\mathcal{H}(G)$, defined according to the following rules (see ['Trees and Matchings'](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9903025) section 2, page 3):

1. Embed $G$ and its [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) $G^{\ast}$ simultaneously in the plane in such a way that any vertex $v$ of $G$ should lie inside its dual face $F_{v}^{\ast}$ in $G^{\ast}$ and any two dual edges of $G$ and $G^{\ast}$ intersect exactly once.
2. Declare all the new edge intersections from step 1 as new vertices and color them in white and all the remaining vertices coming from $G$ and $G^{\ast}$ as black vertices.
3. Denote the resulting graph $\mathcal{H}(G)$ and notice that by construction is bipartite.

***Question:*** Does the bipartite honeycomb lattice arise as the double graph $\mathcal{H}(G)$ of any other graph $G$?

[image]

**Note:** It is indicated in ['Trees and Matchings'](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9903025) that the double graph construction can be generalized to directed graphs and in this case the bipartite honeycomb lattice appears as the double graph a directed triangular lattice, however, I'm interested in undirected graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: in the dual graph construction, all the white vertices created have degree $4$, but the honeycomb lattice is $3$-regular.

Comment: So easy! Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer.